# Angular: List or show existing forms in $scope

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

How can I detect, if a form is currently existing in $scope **at a given time**? (maybe there is a link: **"show current forms in the current controller's $scope"**)

How can I list existing forms in the $scope? (No VanillaJS)

**PSEUDO-CODE:**

```
console log ( existing forms in $scope ) -> list of existing forms
```

EDIT: **Please consider $scope**, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general method to scan child scopes, that's the point of scopes.

For simple case you can:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-init="register(myForm)">
```

where 'register' is method of your top controller.

If you want something more clever - write directive

```
<form name="myForm" register-directive="register(myForm)" unregister="unregister(myForm)"
```

Directive should simply run `register` on creation and `unregister` on scope.$destroy.

Answer (score 0):

if this is your form tag:

```
<form name="myForm" >
```

then your can reach your form (from controller)like this:

```
$scope.myForm
```

Answer (score 0):

Forms are html elements and therefore you can select them with a simple javascript query and then cast them as angular elements (wich at the end are jQuery or jqLite elements):

```
<form name="formNumber1"></form>
<form name="formNumber2"></form>
```

Then you could do:

```
var myForm1 = angular.element('formNumber1');
var allFormsOnThePage = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));
```

Take into account that the allFormsOnThePage will be an array you can iterate on.

Read here for reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Furthermore angular creates a variable in $scope with the same name as your form, for validation and error tracking, so you can check if a concrete form is present just checking if it's not undefined:

```
if ($scope.formNumber2) doWhatYouWant();
```

Answer (score 0):

before access form object you need to wait for angular create them, use a $watch to access them inside controller.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller("MainCtrl",['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.$watch("forms",function(oldV,forms){
     console.log("Number of form:"+ Object.keys(forms).length);
     angular.forEach(forms,function(form,index){
         console.log(form.$name);
        });
    });

    $scope.showCurrentForms = function(){
         console.log($scope.forms);
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="forms.myForm1" >
        <input name="input1"/>
    </form>
    <form name="forms.myForm2" >
        <input name="input2"/>
    </form>
     <form name="forms.myForm3" >
        <input name="input3"/>
    </form>
    <form name="forms.myForm4" >
        <input name="input4"/>
    </form>

    <button ng-click="showCurrentForms()">Current Forms</button>
</div>
```